# how to print directly to a text file in both python 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, stdout, python-2.x

Instead of using `write()`, what are the other way to write to a text file in Python 2 and 3?

```
file = open('filename.txt', 'w')
file.write('some text')
```

Comment: Why would you want other ways to do it? Python in general has very few ways of doing one thing. That is intentional, and good. Using "print" is not equivalent to write, there are subtle differences.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the `print_function` [*future import*](http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html) to get the `print()` behaviour from python3 in python2:

```
from __future__ import print_function
with open('filename', 'w') as f:
    print('some text', file=f)
```

If you do not want that function to append a linebreak at the end, add the `end=''` keyword argument to the `print()` call.

However, consider using `f.write('some text')` as this is much clearer and does not require a `__future__` import.

Answer (score 10):

```
f = open('filename.txt','w')

# For Python 3 use
print('some Text', file=f)

#For Python 2 use
print >>f,'some Text'
```

Comment: Note that this prints with a newline (`\n`) at the end

Comment: @jamylak `, end='')` for `Python 3` will help