# Python lists, pairing and writing

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, typeerror

I have two lists `results`, `xvariables` and I want to write them out, side by side, on a file `results.txt`.
According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760019/best-way-to-print-list-output-in-python) question, the best way to achieve a side by side lists writing is this:

```
f = open("results.txt", "w")

    for idx, vals in zip(results, xvariables):
        print idx
        print ('---'.join(vals))
```

However, i am getting this error:

```
print ('---'.join(vals))
TypeError
```

Additionally i need to pair *each item of the first list* (`results`) *with three items of the second one* (`xvariables`).
The abovementioned lists are like that:

`results` -----> `[20.354999999999997, 20.354999999999997]`

`xvariables` --> `[2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]`

So i need `2,3,4` to be written side by side with `20.354999999999997` and so on.

How am I supposed to  achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
with open("results.txt", "w") as out:
    xiter = iter(xvariables)
    for idx in results:
        print(idx, next(xiter), next(xiter), next(xiter), file=out)
```

The idea is to print the three next available values, and using iter/next is a pretty plain way to do that while you iterate in the usual way over `results`.

Comment: However i am just curious, doesn't your method depend on the way my lists are created? I am using `append` for it and the process is iterative.

Comment: Just for the record, what seems to be the problem  with the `TypeError` i got the first time?

Comment: You were trying to join a single element instead of a sequence.

Comment: `print >>out` <--- Whats `>>`?? Shouldn't it be `print out,idx,...`?

Comment: @Zid: That's the old Python 2 way of printing to a file object.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10445752/4323.  I'll update the answer now for Python 3.

Comment: I see. `print >>f` is now `print(file=f)`